# Storing a class in a classes variable am I doing it right? PHP

Tags: php, variables, object

I am doing this currently,

```
class Page {
    // variable to hold DBC class
    public $dbc;
    /*
        __CONSTRUCT
        Called when class is initiated and sets the dbc variable to hold the DBC class.
    */
    public function __construct() {
        // set the dbc variable to hold the DBC class
        $this -> dbc = new DBC();
    }
    /*
        CREATE PAGE
        Create a page with the option to pass data into it.
    */
    public function create($title, $class, $data = false) {
        // start buffer
        ob_start('gz_handler');
        // content
        content($this -> dbc, $data);
        // end buffer and flush
        ob_end_flush();
    }
```

}

I have simplified the example, but basically I need to pass the object `DBC` to a function inside the method `create`?

Is this considered bad practice as I was using `extends` before but realised there was no way to extract the extended class to a variable?

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're very close to the [dependency injection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dependency_injection) design pattern.

You just have to change your constructor to accept the object as a parameter, like so:

```
public function __construct( $dbc) {
    // set the dbc variable to hold the DBC class
    $this -> dbc = $dbc;
}
```

Then instantiate your class with the database connection, like so:

```
$dbc = new DBC();
$page = new Page( $dbc);
```

This has a variety of benefits, ranging from easier to test, to making a single connection to the database. Imagine you need five `Page` objects - Now you pass them all the same database connection so they do not need to individually create one.

Comment: Ah ok I understand now :) One more question if it is no trouble, but why is this way more preferred than the way I gave? Is it bad to initiate a class inside a class or something like that? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You should pass `DBC` class instance to constructor instead of creating the object inside. This is called `dependency injection`: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dependency_injection .